# objeto session mvc 4 en razor

Tags: c#

Buenas,

Tengo un AccountControler en mi aplicación,  el AccountControler tiene los ActionResult para poder loguearse y desconectarse.

Una vez conectado el usuario (usuario que esta dentro de una tabla en sqlserver), necesito saber como puede obtener los datos de diferentes campos de ese usuario.

Ejemplo(tonto)

Pepito pone su nombre y su password y entra correctamente, pero al entrar tengo que filtrar por el código postal de donde vive, para poder ver un listado de sus calles.

Creo que funciona con el objeto session pero no consigo entender como funciona o como hacerlo.

Comment: Hola Zarios, bienvenido a SOes, podrías detallar por favor? Algo me dice que estas utilizando ASP.net Identity, en tu modelo has agregado el campo del código postal directo al usuario? Dicho campo esta en otra tabla? Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para utilizar las variables de sesión es tan fácil como en tu método Login guardar lo que te sea necesario:

```
string codigoPostal = "XXXXX"; //Obtén la información que necesites
Session["CodigoPostal"]=codigoPostal;
```

Y para luego acceder en cualquier función a lo que has guardado:

```
var codigoPostal=Session["CodigoPostal"] as string; //Fíjate que se tiene que hacer un cast con el as para poder acceder.
```